# How to consume WCF service by dynamically creating client proxy

Tags: c#, wcf

I was trying to generate proxy for a service using the code snippet mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145485/consume-and-invoke-soap-webservices-at-runtime-dynamic-web-service-client-from) but I realized that the snippet is only for asmx services. Is there anyway to do the same for WCF services in c#?

Comment: Your linked example should work for anything that exposes WSDL, have you tried it?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot, yes I tried that. It actually generates the output same as what we get when asmx service is consumed. For instance, the interface defined as ServiceContract in WCF service was generated as partial class with name WsHttpBinding_InterfaceName in the output.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://benmccallum.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/wcf-web-service-wrapper-closing-disposing-and-aborting-best-practices/

Comment: @dustmouse, the code, in the article, is just refactored to create and dispose channel dynamically for every proxy object. In the end Template(T) is still interface or SericeContract  from WCF service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. After much searching found two classes which can do this for us along with help from others.

1. [codecompiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codecompileunit(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [WSDLimporter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.wsdlimporter(v=vs.110).aspx)

These two provide a way to download wsdl at runtime, extract contract and endpoint info and create code in C# or VB which can be compiled to create assembly on which reflection can be used to invoke WCF Service.

Hope this helps somebody someday!