# VB.NET - How to reference a dynamic web service URL avoiding Adding Web Reference?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, soap

I have a requirement to create a small application that will be deployed to a large number of PC's. The application will rely on the PC's hostname as part of its Web Service SOAP calls (ex: http:// PCHOSTNAME /myservice?WSDL)

So because of this, I don't think the "Add Web Reference" option will work, as I won't be able to change it when it's deployed.

Is there a way to set it up so I can specify part of the URL of the web service so I can then make SOAP calls to it?

Comment: This is not true. When you add reference you get strong-typed API for your web service. But you can overwrite your URL any time. You also can call WS without reference. Otherwise, how does AJAX clients do that? Google for it https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2006/04/27/dynamically-invoking-a-web-service/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consume and Invoke SOAP WebServices at Runtime - Dynamic Web Service client from WSDL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145485/consume-and-invoke-soap-webservices-at-runtime-dynamic-web-service-client-from)