# Delphi How to get methods and parameters of a soap server at runtime?

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl

Is there any way I can get the methods and parameters of a soap server at runtime? just like WSDLImp.exe does, but at runtime?

Comment: do you mean without having wsdl?

Comment: I have wsdl, but I did a generic parser, it works, I just wanted to know if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: ok, i do not know about Delphi but you can find some information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145485/consume-and-invoke-soap-webservices-at-runtime-dynamic-web-service-client-from/27146716#27146716 it is also possible to use ServiceDescription by using win32 api.